# Kanban com Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, kanban

Bom dia a todos!

Preciso montar um Kanban, de preferencia com Bootstrap.
Vocês conhecem algum projeto (opensource) pra baixar ele e implementar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após uma pequena pesquisa no google, achei um que deve te agradar, dado que a resposta do [@Flavio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112285/flavio) não agradou.

Eu achei ele no site [bootsnipp](https://www.bootsnipp.com), com este [link direto](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/kanban-board).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda...... eu tinha visto este projeto também pelo Google. 
Só tem um detalhe.... eu não tenho acesso a servidor pra hospedar css e javascript..... tem q estar tudo no html.

Comment: CSS e Javascript você pode fazer dentro do arquivo HTML também. Só é pior pra fazer manutenção, mas poder pode. Só colocar uma tag `<style>` no Header do HTML pra escrever o CSS e uma tag `<script>` pra escrever o Javascript.